# ORA-00905 when running update statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following update statement in Oracle

```
UPDATE PAY_PMT
SET INTER_COMPANY = CASE INTER_COMPANY_ID
WHEN 1 THEN 'Y';
ELSE 'N';
END CASE;
WHERE ID != 1
/
```

But when I execute this, I get following error message:**ORA-00905: missing keyword**

What is wrong?

Comment: Try removing the semicolons `;`.

Comment: A `case` is ended using `END` not `END CASE` (and of course without a `;`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just used 3 semicolons in an update. In this case it means you have 4 statements.
The first is

```
UPDATE PAY_PMT
SET INTER_COMPANY = CASE INTER_COMPANY_ID
WHEN 1 THEN 'Y';
```

The second is:

```
ELSE 'N';
```

The third is:

```
END CASE;
```

And the fourth is:

```
WHERE ID != 1
```

the solution is to use semicolon only at the end of the statement, and the case was not correct.

```
 UPDATE PAY_PMT
    SET INTER_COMPANY = CASE
        WHEN INTER_COMPANY_ID = 1 THEN 'Y'
        ELSE 'N'
    END
 WHERE ID != 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon after the When and Else is wrong, the use of the alias case is not good either

```
UPDATE PAY_PMT
SET INTER_COMPANY = CASE INTER_COMPANY_ID
WHEN 1 THEN 'Y'
ELSE 'N'
END 
WHERE ID != 1;
```

The query will stop at the first ; and move to the next block to process.

Answer (score 0):

To add on more:

When you're entering an SQL statement into SQL*Plus, it needs to know when you're done with it, especially if the command spans multiple rows. Therefore, it requires a *terminal character* character which can be set with the set sqlterminator. By default, this character is the *semicolon* :

What has this to do with the '/', the last line of your update statement ?

When you entered an SQL statement, SQL*plus filled something what it calls a buffer. This buffer can be shown with the list command:

```
SQL> list
  1  select *
  2  from
  3* dual
SQL>
```

(Note: I only entered list, the rest is returned)

The / now executes what is currently in the buffer. Lets try that:

```
SQL> /

D
-
X
```

As can be seen, the same query is executed.